# Restart the Program when a kill signal has executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, signals

I currently use `os.kill(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, 1)` to kill a thread because I wasn't able to use the normal method. But as soon as it has completed that command I want to restart the whole program. My first idea was to open a separate cmd when a task is called but didn't find any method to do that. Is there a workaround to this?

I also tried having a separate file restart the file if it doesn't run. But then it starts running in the wrong cmd which will result in that `os.kill(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT, 1)` will kill the entire process.

Comment: Can you use the path to the executable? If so, use os.popen or subprocess.run to start it.

Comment: Unfununtly using either os or subprocess to run the file. It still ends up running in the same terminal which will result in that os.kill will kill both files